# Digigram driver in 14.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 14.04

I am trying to install Digigram VX222 driver and I get the following error. Somewhat new to Ubuntu, any thoughts?

```
root@PanthersSpanish:/usr/src/alsa/INSTALL-VX# sh installvx-alsa1.0.2
installvx-alsa1.0.2: 21: installvx-alsa1.0.2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing :

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-firmware-loaders
```